# How do I implement it like Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, architecture, aop, aspect

I am currently working on a project to manage the reservation system.
There is a new requirement, which is to be able to keep track of all booking status changes.
I hope this does not affect the existing logic and exists as an independent module.

At first I thought of AOP, but there are some problems.
This request should record how what data was changed by what action.

I thought that I could extract the different data by applying AOP to the save method of the repository.
However, this is not possible because there are many different actions that update data.

For example, for reservation, the update by using the save method in the repository, but this method is used in various actions such as check in, check out and etc..
Therefore, the difference in data can be obtained, but it is not possible to tell which action the data was updated.

```java
@Service
public class BookingService {
    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    public Booking create(Booking booking) {
        return bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }

    public void update(Booking booking) {
        Booking oldBooking = bookingRepository.findById(booking.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Entity not found"));
        oldBooking.update(booking);

        bookingRepository.save(oldBooking);
    }

    public void checkIn(long id) {
        Booking booking = bookingRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Entity not found"));

        booking.setStatus(Booking.Status.CheckIn);

        bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }
}
```

And since I use AOP, I don't want the parameters or result values of the existing logic to fit in a certain form.

While contemplating how to solve this, how about using the method used by Mockito.
In Mockito, We can know when a method is executed within a method.

Wouldn't it be possible to create a method like this, for example?

```java
@Aspect
public class BookingHistory {
    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    @Around("execution(* *Service.update(..))")
    public void update(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
        long id = getBookingId(proceedingJoinPoint);
        Booking origin = getBooking(id);

        final DiffData diffData;
        when(bookingRepository::save).thenReturn(result -> diffData = diff(origin, result));
        saveHistory("UPDATE", "Booking", diffData);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement "when", "thenReturn" etc in Mockito.

Could I get some hints to implement Mockito?

And if not this way, is there any other good way?

Comment: What persistency are you using? JPA? Plain JDBC? or...

Comment: Spring data JPA.

Comment: Assuming yuo are using Hibernate, just use Hibernate Envers. Which does this out-of-the-box or if you want something else you can use JaVers as well. You don't need to roll your own. YOu could even, if all else fails, do this with a trigger on the database to copy the original data to an audit table. No need to do it in java if you want.

Comment: This is simply not how AOP works. If you want to influence the return value of `save`, just write an advice with a pointcut intercepting its execution, do your diff thingy there and save to the audit log. If you would post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I could run it locally and come up with a concrete suggestion how to do that. You are hiding information at the moment, e.g. what `getBookingId(proceedingJoinPoint)` does, what the `Booking` class looks like etc. But from what I see, you could easily solve the problem using AOP if you don't like Javers.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito is a testing framework and should only be used for unit testing. If you want to keep track of which method changes the data using Spring's AOP, you can use custom annotations. With custom annotations, you can just pass the value which identifies the action and do whatever you want to it, e.g.: log it, publish it to MQ for analytics, etc. Try the following [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation) on creating custom annotations and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-get-advised-method-info) on how to get the method's caller information.